# Sips image resize: Background cover

Tags: image-processing, sips

Using SIPS, I can proportionally resize an image using `sips -Z 256` to reduce the width and height of my image to a size no larger than 256px. Over a padded background fill, this produces a result similar to a CSS `background-size: contain` resize.

However, what I'd like to get is a crop of 256x256, similar to a CSS `background-size: cover` resize, where the width and height are proportionally reduced to a canvas no smaller than 256px.

`sips -Z 256 "$file" --cropToHeightWidth 256 256` is close to what I'm after, but the `Z` flag is leaving one side too small.

[image: Background: Contain]

How would I achieve this result, instead?

[image: Background: Cover]

It would be nice if I could apply something like cv2 to get a `background:cover` style proportional scale with a crop position which defaults to a center-crop, but adjusts the position to prevent faces from being cropped out of the image.

Comment: You probably need to get the picture dimensions first, then do the math in `bash` and use `sips` again to resize/crop.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean by "leaving one side too small." Could you post an image that shows what that looks like?

Comment: @JMY1000 I added an example of the current result with SIPS.

Comment: I see. Given you also want to set a mask, it seems like at this point your best bet is either with ImageMagick or OpenCV (if you want something like facial detection.)